# Можно ли указать переменной название столбца, по которому нужно сортировать результат запроса?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Во фронтенде пользователь может указать, по какой колонке сортировать, и мне этот параметр передаётся символьной переменной.

Можно ли указать в запросе колонку, по которой нужно сортировать, если имя этой колонки содержится в символьной переменной?

До меня это делали через динамический запрос. То есть, например, в переменной `i_sort_by` хранится столбец, по которому надо сортировать, а в `i_sort_direction` хранится направление и получается такой запрос:

```
OPEN o_cursor FOR '
    SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
    ORDER BY '|| i_sort_by || ' ' || i_sort_direction;
```

Такой код сложнее поддерживать, читать и отлаживать. Хотел бы сделать статическим запросом, но не знаю как, чтобы получилось что-то такое:

```
OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
    ORDER BY i_sort_by i_sort_direction;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подстановочными переменными нельзя указать имена идентификаторов (колонок в данном случае) и отдельные клаузы или опции статического запроса.

Стандартный способ решения - использовать условные операторы. Пробуйте:

```
create table t1 (c1, c2) as
    select 1, 2 from dual union all 
    select 2, 1 from dual
/
var rc refcursor
declare 
    sortCol varchar2 (8) := 'c1'; 
    sortDir varchar2 (8) := 'desc'; 
begin 
    open :rc for 
        select * from t1 
        order by
        case sortDir when 'asc' then 
            case sortCol when 'c1' then c1 else c2 end end asc, 
        case sortDir when 'desc' then 
            case sortCol when 'c1' then c1 else c2 end end desc 
        ;
end;
/
        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         2          1
         1          2
```